# Dojo-Dgrid Dgrid tutoriel

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I'm a new developer and im trying the framework Dojo-Toolkit and especially d-grid .
So i follow the tutorial (http://dgrid.io/tutorials/1.0/hello_dgrid/) here is my index :

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello dgrid!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="djgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="claro.css">
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="grid"></div>


    <!-- load Dojo -->

    <script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script src="dojoconfig.js"></script>
    <script>

      require([ 'dgrid/Grid', 'dojo/domReady!' ], function (Grid) {
    var data = [
        { first: 'Bob', last: 'Barker', age: 89 },
        { first: 'Vanna', last: 'White', age: 55 },
        { first: 'Pat', last: 'Sajak', age: 65 }
    ];

    var grid = new Grid({
        columns: {
            first: 'First Name',
            last: 'Last Name',
            age: 'Age'
        }
    }, 'grid');
    grid.renderArray(data);
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So when i run on "localhost/DOJO/index.html" i get this error :

> http://localhost/DOJO/dgrid/Grid.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I dont understand why  it search on this location ... and also i get 2 :

> Error: scriptError(…)

If someone can tell me how that work that ll be lovely :)

Comment: Where are dojo and dgrid located on your server?  Did you follow dgrid's [installation instructions](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid#installation)?  Also, if you're defining `dojoConfig` in `dojoconfig.js`, that needs to be loaded *before* `dojo.js`.

Comment: They are located at "C:\wamp\www\DOJO" and "C:\wamp\www\DOJO" , what should i have on my dojoconfig.js ? i replace it before dojo.js btw thanks !

Comment: If I'm interpreting you correctly then you have www\DOJO\dojo and www\DOJO\dgrid, but the 404 you're getting would suggest that your dgrid folder isn't at that location.  If your dojo and dgrid packages are siblings, that *should* just work...

Comment: Thank you,:) so yes, i did not have the right directory structure on my server ...rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

Even if the problem seems solved, this answer will clarify Ken's comments and help other people who try to integrate DGrid to Dojo.

Your code require a `dgrid/Grid` module the same way it require the `dojo\domReady`

```
require([ 'dgrid/Grid','dojo/domReady!'], ...);
```

so your dgrid folder have **to be at the same level** as your dojo folder.

> - DOJO
>
>   > - app
>   > - dgrid
>   > - dijit
>   > - dojo
>   > - dojox

In your dojoConfig.js, you should have a line like :

```
packages: ['dojo', 'dijit', 'dojox', 'app', 'dgrid'],
```